# How to process url(...) in external module with webpack

Tags: webpack

I have style that's defined in an external module X (another package in node_modules), like:

- src

  - my-module.js
- node_modules

  - x.js

The module contains this:

```
// FIXME: remove disable comment after https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3987 is released
// Fonts and other resources are relative to the module that imports this style module, so calculate the URL
let url = import.meta.url;
url = url.replace(url.split("/").pop(), "");
/* tslint:enable */
// See also issue #1433 about font loading
export let typo = `

@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman';
    src: url('${url}/../../../fonts/Helvetica_Neue/398D5F_0_0.woff2')  format('woff2');
};
```

How Can I get webpack to proces/handle the `url()` stuff so webpack replaces the url and copies the images/fonts etc. to the output directory? I know the same logic is done in the css loaded, but in my use case the style is contained in a JS module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this.  It doesn't make sense to try to make Webpack smart enough to find every string in a JS file that might be used as inline style later.

Instead, you should be using the [copy plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to move the assets of your dependencies where they're expected to be.  For example, I use a package called `cesium`, and in my config I have something like

```js
import CopyPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";

export const cesiumSource = resolve("./node_modules/cesium/Source");
export const cesiumTarget = "CesiumStatic";

module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [{
                from: join(cesiumSource, "Assets"),
                to: cesiumTarget + "/Assets",
            }]
        })
    ]
}
```

This copies the whole Assets tree to `./dist/CesiumStatic/Assets`.  The package has a mechanism at runtime to tell it where to expect its assets to be, and uses the path I give it to build URLs for fonts, JSON data, images, etc.

Your dependency looks like it's less configurable and just expects its stuff to be in `/fonts/`.  You'd need to set up a CopyPlugin to grab the font file from wherever it's stored (presumably, `./node_modules/x/fonts/`?) and put it in your build directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a file-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) into your webpack config. file-loader will resolve files into a url, and emits that file into the output directory for you.

```json
{
    'test': /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    'exclude': /node_modules/,
    'use': [
      {
        'loader': 'file-loader',
        'options': {
          'name': '[name].[ext]',
          'outputPath': `some/fonts/folder/`
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then, you can simply `require()` that font file, and use it in your `url()`:

```js
const font = require('/actual/source/location/of/fonts/Helvetica_Neue/398D5F_0_0.woff2');

export let typo = `
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman';
    src: url('${font}')  format('woff2');
};
`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned the code is in an external package of which I cannot change the code. Is there another way to achieve this? The `polymer-webpack-loader` for example also does the job, but only for Polymer elements.